# .htaccess parameter redirect rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, hosting

I want to redirect the domain to 'function.php' by the .htaccess

If I want to redirect the domains below according to each rule, how should I write the .htaccess file?

1. "ex.com" to "ex.com/function.php"
2. ex.com / {3 characters to "tt"}, {remaining digits to "num"}

tt parameter always has 3 characters. num parameter is random, it can be 1, or 2 ~ 8.

```
"ex.com/3Ad32" to "ex.com/function.php?tt=3Ad&num=32"
"ex.com/5eX9901" to "ex.com/function.php?tt=5eX&num=9901"
"ex.com/5Db930" to "ex.com/function.php?tt=5Db&num=930"
```

3.If the domain has a parameter, it redirect it equally.

```
"ex.com/3Ad32?fo=test" to "ex.com/function.php?tt=3Ad&num=32&fo=test"
"ex.com/5eX9901?fo=ops" to "ex.com/function.php?tt=5eX&num=9901&fo=ops"
"ex.com/5Db930fo=thx&te=on" to "ex.com/function.php?tt=5Db&num=930&fo=thx&te=on"
```

I don't even know if .htaccess file can cut some of the URLs (like 3 characters to the "tt" parameter)

All purposes are because parameters are needed in function.php.

```
<?php
$type = $_GET['tt'];
$num = $_GET['num'];
$fo = $_GET['fo'];
if(!empty($fo)){
   $fo = "n";
}

....
```

------new question.

If I have two domains, and only the subdomain "ex.com" needs to work, should I write it like this? Only Maindomain has the SSL.

```
-----current .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main.com$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?ex.com$
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9A-Za-z]{3})([0-9]+)$ /function.php?tt=$1$num=$2 [QSA, L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your .htaccess or your Apache conf:

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9A-Za-z]{3})([0-9]+)$ /function.php?tt=$1&num=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Where:

- `^/?` - The URL path starts with an optional slash
- `([0-9A-Za-z]{3})` - Exactly 3 digits or letters in capturing parenthesis that will become `$1`
- `([0-9]+)` - One or more digits in capturing parenthesis that will become `$2`
- `$` - Matches the end of the URL path
- `QSA` - "query string append" which will preserve the other parameters that already exist in the query string
- `L` - "last" which prevents other rewrite rules from running when this one matches

This rule will NOT redirect and change the URL.  If you would prefer that users get redirected, you would add `R=301` to the comma separated list of flags, ie. `[QSA,L,R=301]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :> referring to your answer, I wrote the custom .htaccess code and edited question again. Will that work?

Comment: If you are mixing this with other rewrite rules you only need one `RewriteEngine on`.  This rule is not compatible with the `. /index.php` rule for your front controller, so this rule needs to come before it.